# Change way of view data from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I need a help with way of view data from database.
I have table with content from DB, like that:

```
<tbody>
  <% @scripts.each do |text| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= text.book %></td>
      <td><%= text.chapter %></td>
      <td><%= text.line %></td>
      <td><%= text.body %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Output is like that:

```
book    chapter     line    body
  1         1        1       1 Lorem ipsum....
...
  1         1        10      10 Lorem ipsum....
```

I want to switch way of show book number as book title. I was thinking about Constant board, like:

in Script model:

```
BOOKS = {"1" => "Book1", "2" => "Book2" .... "66" => "Book66"

def book_name
  BOOKS[book_number]
end
```

in Script controller:

```
def book_number
  params[:script][:book]
end
```

in view file:

```
<tbody>
  <% @scripts.each do |text| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= text.book_name %></td>
      <td><%= text.chapter %></td>
      <td><%= text.line %></td>
      <td><%= text.body %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

When I done this i receive:

```
undefined local variable or method `book_number' for #<Script:0x007fdf5ed16a88>
```

If I use

```
<td><%= text.book.book_name %></td>
```

I receive:

```
undefined method `book_name' for "1":Fixnum
```

Any ideas? Please help.

Or maybe if I can add new record as "book_name" to database as migration what do this as new table with name of all books added to all books records 1-66 next to book number.

Current my DB schema looks like:

```
create_table :scripts do |t|
  t.text :book
  t.integer :chapter
  t.integer :line
  t.text :body
```

And I could use it instead

```
<td><%= text.book %></td>
```

Waiting for You answers mates! Regards!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to is to create a custom getter (I think? It's either getter or setter!):

```
#app/models/script.rb
Class Script < ActiveRecord::Base
   def name
     "Book#{id}"
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@scripts = Script.all
@scripts.each do |book|
   book.name
end
```

---

**Objects**

It's vitally important you know *how* this works

The problem you have is that you are currently trying to set model / object attributes in your *controller*. This is a big no-no

Rails is an [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) system, meaning that everything you do with it will revolve around [*objects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). In the case of Rails, the *objects* are defined in the `Model`, as per the [MVC Programming Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

This means that every time you build an *object* (call a `Model`), you need to be able to provide the various attributes / settings for the object inside the model (nowhere else). It's difficult to describe so succinctly, but here's something to consider:

[image]

If you're using the model to populate specific attributes, you need to ensure they are set in the model itself. Anything else will not work as you want.

--

I can explain more if you need

Answer (score 0):

try `<td><%= BOOK[text.book.to_s] %></td>`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from error, text.book returns an integer, which is book_number, so to make it working (according to your current logic, which is kind of twisted), you should try something like this:
Replace `book_name` method implementation in your Script model with this:

```
def book_name(book_number)
  BOOKS[book_number]
end
```

because your current implementation requires book_number, but you arent providing it. In your view, you call it, typing book_number to book_name method:
`<td><%= text.book_name(text.book.to_s) %></td>`